# Where this row of frozen trees is placed?

Tags: identify-this, winter

[image]

I'd fancy to visit the place portrayed in the photo above. What is the name of the city in the background??

The original of the above image (at least in my PC) is placed at

```
/mnt/windows/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/MateBook/Wallpaper07.png
```

I have tried a Google Image search to no particular avail, I just found that the photo is associated with Huawei (but I already knew that…) and that many sites that sell winter related items use the same image.

Possible hints:

- there is a castle or a cathedral (at any rate, a building larger than the others) in the largest gap between the trees in the right of the photo,
- there is the tip of something (possibly an antenna?) that just pops up over the top of the trees in the centre of the photo.

---

PS I forgot to mention that the original PNG file (the posted image has been scaled and converted to JPG) does not contain any comment.

Comment: I tried to add a [trees] tag but it doesn't exist and I have not enough rep (297<300)...

Comment: It appears to be available on [Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/winter-landscape-89744419), and is attributed to a Romanian photographer named Mircea Bezergheanu.  You could try contacting him.

Comment: @gboffi, there is no [trees]  tag in Travel as it is not relevant to the topic of the site. Not all details in a question need to have a tag.

Comment: @Willeke OK, thank you.  I think that a trees tag may be relevant for some question, but I understand your POV.

Comment: @gboffi, I did run a search on the site and checked out quite a few questions with trees mentioned in the question and non of them did require a [trees] tag. All of them were tagged well enough without it, using existing tags.

Comment: What exactly are you interested in? The buildings in the background? Rows of trees on the bank of a water body can be found in millions of places,so what's so special about these?

Comment: @TooTea I have edited the body of the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is Danube river. I found the same scenery but different angle here at
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/2n3e78/frosty_trees_along_the_danube_river/)

Comment: Danube River is almost 3ooo km long. Should I like to TRAVEL to the site…